# Concurrency between many machines running the same web app on the server side

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, concurrency

This is a pretty open question. I was wondering: how can you handle concurrency if you have a web application that is hosted on many computers on the server side? For example, how can you manage a simple stack if you have an ASP .NET application running on different machines with each one having its own memory? Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly: how do multiple Web servers co-ordinate to return responses?

In general a farm of Web servers will serve up exactly the same HTML to clients when a particular request arrives. If there's a need to store state - suppose the user posts back a form with data, or session state is used to keep track of a shopping cart - then you'll need some shared mechanism to do that.

There's plenty of ways to share state between multiple instances of a Web server:

- A database can store data that needs to be persisted indefinitely, such as user profile information
- Similarly, a key-value store (like the Windows Azure table storage) can be used for permanent storage, with advantages in performance over less flexibility when querying
- Shared session state (using a database or central session state server) can store moderately-persistent data that's local to the current session

Things can get complex, though:

- If data is cached, you may need to have a mechanism to expire the cache on each Web server
- Eventually, contention over shared session storage or database storage can negate the advantages of multiple Web servers

To get around this some systems use the principle of "eventual consistency", where, for instance, a profile update might not be replicated immediately to every server in a cluster. Not-quite-fresh data is sometimes regarded as good enough.

As you can tell this is a complex subject and I've only really skated around the edges of it.

The good news is that ***generally you won't need to bother*** as unless you're creating a *very* large or complex site most modern server hardware can handle many tens of requests per second without breaking into a sweat. It's only when you start to move above a few dozen *simultaneous* requests per second that Web farms start to be necessary.

Comment: Thank you, that was a very insightful answer. It's actually a shared session state that I need. Do you happen to know a good basic tutorial to get me started?

Comment: @mieli - try here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx - easiest to set up is the Session State server, although that does give your application a single point of failure. It's a fine solution if performance is what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

[Jeremy McGee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621403/concurrency-between-many-machines-running-the-same-web-app-on-the-server-side/7621767#7621767) covers most of the important points. One other angle is that many web farm setups use "sticky sessions" where one session stays with a particular server. It is a great compromise between allowing scale and having to build, buy or configure lots of state management across your web server pool.

The big problem kicks in when you have to scale the underlying data store out. There be dragons.

Answer (score 0):

You use reverse ajax (Comet) in different channels like using the web server [Meteor](http://www.meteorserver.org).
Facebook and Twitter use the same asynchronous event methods.